# How to remove paint in dent of guitar

Tags: sanding, refinishing, hardwood

I've sanded the body of my guitar but there are still some dents with paint in it. It's ash wood. My question is how I can remove the paint in these dents?
[image: Dent one]
[image: Dent two]

Comment: Is that the neck or some other thick bit? If it is, you might be able to reduce the dent a little by steaming it. (If it's a thin part, forget it.)

Comment: ... just saw your other question... definitely try steaming it. Put a damp cloth on top of the wood and press on it with a warm iron. It won't completely fix the dent, but should reduce it and will help with paint removal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways: chemical, and physical.

chemical: use paint stripper. if there is still finish left on the body you'll want to test this in an inconspicuous spot to make sure that finish isn't affected undesirably by the stripper.

physical: get in there with blades and picks to pull out the paint.

You'll ultimately probably need both - using small stiff brushes and picks in combination with the stripper.

Comment: I'll try it with I blade but thank you for the chemical hint... I'll try this if the physical way doesn't work... Thank you :)